# Zend: HTTP Error 500

Tags: php

I have one Zend project developed on my server (where everything works fine), but when i transferred it to production server I keep getting the Internal Server Error message and the website won't work.

What I can't understand is that the admin part (www.mysite.com/admin) works fine, but when I try to access website (www.mysite.com) it interrupts.

I know this is a really long shot, but does anyone have any suggestion where to start searching for the cause of the problem?

Comment: Look at your webserver error logs or turn on display_errors.

Comment: Make sure the database schema/login information is up to date?

Comment: I don't have access to web server logs, but I'll ask them from ISP.

Database info is good because to access the admin part I have to login, and I can do that successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Up to my knowledge the 500 error is generated when the web server does not get an answer back from scripting engine in time, which would be PHP in case of Zend. It would be interesting to know if you receive this error immediately or after some time. If it takes some time your application may be hanging in a loop.

Comment: It breaks almos immediately, lets say it takes him not more than 1 second.

It shouldn't be any loop because everything works fine on the test server. The problem is probably in some file permissions or server configuration, but I totally unable to detect where and what.

Comment: In that case I guess you are facing some error in your PHP script/environment. You can write debug messages silently to a file at major points (like bootstrap.php, controllers, actions etc.), so you can see how far you get in your application. This will get you some sense of a feeling where the culprit might be.